RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 3, 3, 3], expected input[3, 1, 13, 1065] to have 3 channels, but got 1 channels instead
I am getting the following error while building a CNN for an audio classification assignment (3 classifiers (parent, infant, other), 28 training files - stft first, and then changed to mfcc in the code below). I have been running into this error and also the expected 4D but got 3D error as well. Tried unsqueezed methods with the help of chatgpt, as well as pre-trained models. Any guidance would be appreciated! (Code shown after error)
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-197-fa69a532d442> in <cell line: 7>()
      6 epochs = 10
      7 for epoch in range(epochs):
----> 8     train_loss, train_accuracy = train_loop(train_loader, model, loss_fn, optimizer, device)
      9     val_loss, val_accuracy = val_loop(val_loader, model, loss_fn, device)
     10 

7 frames
<ipython-input-195-792161567894> in train_loop(dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer, device)
     10         data = data.float()  # Convert input tensor to float32
     11         optimizer.zero_grad()
---> 12         output = model(data)
     13         loss = loss_fn(output, target)
     14         loss.backward()

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1509             return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1510         else:
-> 1511             return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
   1512 
   1513     def _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1518                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1519                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1520             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1521 
   1522         try:

<ipython-input-183-0caa9fc655c1> in forward(self, x)
     23 
     24     def forward(self, x):
---> 25         x = self.conv1(x)
     26         x = self.relu1(x)
     27         x = self.batchnorm1(x)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1509             return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1510         else:
-> 1511             return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
   1512 
   1513     def _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1518                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1519                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1520             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1521 
   1522         try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in forward(self, input)
    458 
    459     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 460         return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    461 
    462 class Conv3d(_ConvNd):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
    454                             weight, bias, self.stride,
    455                             _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
--> 456         return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
    457                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    458 

RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 3, 3, 3], expected input[3, 1, 13, 1065] to have 3 channels, but got 1 channels instead

Here is my code:
#**Objective**

Conversational switch off (turn taking vocalizations) between people/agents that will allow us to count these interactions and compute the rate of speech switching.

## Load drive and packages
"""

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')

# !pip install torchmetrics
# !pip install evaluate

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import tensorflow as tf
from torchmetrics import Accuracy
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
import glob
import librosa
import pickle
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, random_split
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torchvision.models as models

"""## Make dictionary w/ labels"""

# Path to the directory containing CSV files
directory_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Capstone/capstone_csv_files/"

# Get a list of all CSV files in the directory
csv_files = glob.glob(directory_path + "*.csv")

cd "/content/drive/MyDrive/Capstone/capstone_csv_files"

# Create an empty dictionary to store MFCCs
mfcc_dict = {}
labels = []
# Loop through each CSV file
for file in csv_files:
    # Extract the file name without extension
    file_name = file.split("/")[-1].split(".csv")[0]

    # Read the CSV file into a DataFrame
    df = pd.read_csv(file, header = None)

    # Convert dB matrix to linear scale
    stft_matrix_db = df.values
    stft_matrix = librosa.db_to_power(stft_matrix_db)

    # Compute MFCCs
    mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(S=stft_matrix, sr=44100, n_mfcc=13)  # Example: n_mfcc=13

    mfccs_with_channels = mfccs.reshape(1, mfccs.shape[0], mfccs.shape[1])  # Add a channel dimension

    # Determine label based on file name
    if "caregiver" in file_name:
        label = 0
    elif "infant" in file_name:
        label = 1
    else:
        label = 2

    mfcc_dict[file_name] = [mfccs, label]

"""## Making Tensor"""

# Determine the maximum shape of the MFCC arrays
max_time_steps = max(mfcc_array.shape[1] for mfcc_array, _ in mfcc_dict.values())
max_features = next(iter(mfcc_dict.values()))[0].shape[0]  # Assuming all matrices have the same number of features

# Pad or crop each MFCC matrix to match the maximum shape
for file_name, (mfccs, label) in mfcc_dict.items():
    mfccs_padded = np.pad(mfccs, ((0, 0), (0, max_time_steps - mfccs.shape[1])), mode='constant')
    mfcc_dict[file_name] = (mfccs_padded, label)

X_list = [mfcc for mfcc, _ in mfcc_dict.values()]
X_tensor = torch.tensor(X_list)

X_tensor.shape

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

num_samples = 28 # number of files
y_labels = [0] * 9 + [1] * 9 + [2] * (num_samples - 18)

# Convert the list of labels to a PyTorch tensor
y_tensor = torch.tensor(y_labels)

y_tensor.shape

"""## Split Data"""

print("X_tensor shape:", X_tensor.shape)
print("y_tensor shape:", y_tensor.shape)

dataset_all = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(X_tensor, y_tensor)
len(dataset_all)

# Define the sizes for training, testing, and validation sets
train_size = int(0.7 * len(dataset_all))
test_size = int(0.15 * len(dataset_all))
val_size = len(dataset_all) - train_size - test_size

# Split the dataset into training, testing, and validation sets
dataset_train, dataset_test, dataset_val = torch.utils.data.random_split(
    dataset_all, [train_size, test_size, val_size], generator=torch.Generator().manual_seed(42)
)

batch_size = 3

train_loader = DataLoader(dataset_train, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=2, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(dataset_test, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=2, shuffle=False)
val_loader = DataLoader(dataset_val, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=2, shuffle=False)

"""## Build CNN Model

Building the CNN, for the output layer we should use Softmax since we are multi-classifying (0 or 1), for the hidden layer we should start with ReLu for its efficiency, and Adam for the optimizer, but may have to move to SGD (or deploy both for our model - do one in the first half and deploy other for the second half).
"""

class CNNModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNNModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.batchnorm1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)
        self.maxpool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.batchnorm2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
        self.maxpool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.relu3 = nn.ReLU()
        self.batchnorm3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(128)
        self.maxpool3 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(128 * 3 * 1065, 256)
        self.relu4 = nn.ReLU()
        self.batchnorm4 = nn.BatchNorm1d(256)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, 3)
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)
        x = self.batchnorm1(x)
        x = self.maxpool1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.relu2(x)
        x = self.batchnorm2(x)
        x = self.maxpool2(x)
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.relu3(x)
        x = self.batchnorm3(x)
        x = self.maxpool3(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.relu4(x)
        x = self.batchnorm4(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.softmax(x)
        return x

"""## Train and Validation Functions"""

def train_loop(dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer, device):
    model.train()
    total_loss = 0.0
    correct = 0
    total = 0

    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(dataloader):
        data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
        data = data.unsqueeze(1)  # Add channel dimension
        data = data.float()  # Convert input tensor to float32
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data)
        loss = loss_fn(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        total_loss += loss.item()
        _, predicted = output.max(1)
        total += target.size(0)
        correct += predicted.eq(target).sum().item()

    accuracy = 100.0 * correct / total
    return total_loss, accuracy

def val_loop(dataloader, model, loss_fn, device):
    model.eval()
    total_loss = 0.0
    correct = 0
    total = 0

    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(dataloader):
            data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
            data = data.unsqueeze(1)  # Add channel dimension
            data = data.float()  # Convert input tensor to float32
            output = model(data)
            loss = loss_fn(output, target)

            total_loss += loss.item()
            _, predicted = output.max(1)
            total += target.size(0)
            correct += predicted.eq(target).sum().item()

    accuracy = 100.0 * correct / total
    return total_loss, accuracy

"""## Run Model"""

# Example usage:
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model = CNNModel().to(device)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

train_losses = []
train_accuracies = []
val_losses = []
val_accuracies = []

epochs = 10
for epoch in range(epochs):
    train_loss, train_accuracy = train_loop(train_loader, model, loss_fn, optimizer, device)
    val_loss, val_accuracy = val_loop(val_loader, model, loss_fn, device)

    train_losses.append(train_loss)
    train_accuracies.append(train_accuracy)
    val_losses.append(val_loss)
    val_accuracies.append(val_accuracy)

    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{epochs}:")
    print(f"Train Loss: {train_loss:.4f}, Train Accuracy: {train_accuracy:.2f}%")
    print(f"Validation Loss: {val_loss:.4f}, Validation Accuracy: {val_accuracy:.2f}%")

